# Getting null values from jsf inputText in Manage bean

Tags: jsf-2

I am facing weird issue in jsf inputText. On browser it is showing the manage bean name and the variable name in input box (i.e. #{loginModel.userName}). the following is my jsf page code

```
<body>
<f:view>
    <h:form>
        <h:outputLabel value="Username"></h:outputLabel>
        <h:inputText value="#{loginModel.userName}"></h:inputText>
        <h:outputLabel value="Password"></h:outputLabel>
        <h:inputSecret value="#{loginModel.password}"></h:inputSecret>
        <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{loginModel.process}" ></h:commandButton>
    </h:form>
</f:view>
</body>
```

My manage bean code is

```
public class LoginModel {

    private String userName;
    private String password;
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String process(){

        System.out.println("Logged in user id is "+this.getUserName()+" and password to access is "+this.getPassword());
        return "Submit";
    }

}
```

and my faces-config.xml file

```
<managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>loginModel</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>net.varun.dto.LoginModel</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

and following is my output on browser as well as i am getting null when i click on submit button

Answer (score 1):

try the following code:

Change your h:commandButton for the primefaces process, `partialSubmit` and `ajax`

```
<body>
<f:view>
    <h:form>
        <h:outputLabel value="Username"></h:outputLabel>
        <h:inputText value="#{loginModel.userName}"></h:inputText>
        <h:outputLabel value="Password"></h:outputLabel>
        <h:inputSecret value="#{loginModel.password}"></h:inputSecret>
        <p:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{loginModel.process}" process="@form" partialSubmit="true" ajax="true" />
    </h:form>
</f:view>
</body>
```

So you can put a breakpoint in your process method for see the update values.